# Можно ли в Retrofit2 отправлять картинку, как тип File?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Столкнулись с проблемой, что я отправляю картинки на сервер в виде Base64, а бекенд просит, чтобы я отправлял файлом, есть ли такая возможность? В интернете решений не нашел, поэтому обращаюсь к вам за помощью. Бекенд говорит, что на Postman есть даже тип File, и мол почему я не могу в этом формате отправлять картинки.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953457/how-to-upload-an-image-file-in-retrofit-2

Comment: @Shams Спасибо, конечно, но я это и прочие методы видел. Тут вопрос не в том, как отправлять, а в том, можно ли отправлять файлом без преобразования в поток байтов?